# cmake_parse_arguments missing on CMake re-run

Tags: cmake

I am trying to write a function which uses [`cmake_parse_arguments`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/CMakeParseArguments.html) to interpret the parameters. This works fine when running `cmake` in a fresh build directory. However, any time I try to re-run `cmake`, CMake seems to believe the function does not exist:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:6 (CMAKE_PARSE_ARGUMENTS):
  Unknown CMake command "CMAKE_PARSE_ARGUMENTS".
```

I feel like I'm missing something obvious. I am using CMake 3.3.2 on Arch Linux.

Comment: Have you included `CMakeParseArguments`?

Comment: That's my problem. Although it doesn't explain why it works on a fresh directory...CMake behavior is perplexing to me.

Comment: I guess some Find packages are cached and not rerun. They included the missing package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Include `CMakeParseArguments` with

```
include(CMakeParseArguments)
```

Probably it worked the first time because other Find* files included the file already. As the result of the Find* files are cached and not re-run, they no longer included CMakeParseArguments.